# Can't set attribute of type sObject

Tags: lightning-aura-components, lightning-web-components

I have an attribute of type sObject in my custom component:

```
<aura:attribute name="selectedRecord" type="sObject" default="{}"/>
```

I am trying to set it, but it doesn't seem to save.

```
    var selectedRecord = {"Id":"aaa","Name":"bbb"};
    component.set("v.selectedRecord" , selectedRecord); 
    alert("Handler: "+component.get("v.selectedRecord").Name);
```

It say that `component.get("v.selectedRecord")` is undefined, what am I doing wrong?

Comment: Hi. Can you please post more code, because I've tried this snipper and it worked as expected.

Comment: Try defining your default with some object params - `<aura:attribute name="selectedRecord" type="Map" default="{'Name':'','Id':''}"/>`, also try defining as a Map instead - you can add the `sobjectType` field prior to save.

Comment: Hi, I still can't figure it out so I made a work around by having 2 separate attribute of type string, one for name, and one for id, which worked.